# Firestore pending writes not uploading when using 'await' with 'firestore.doc().set()'. What am I missing?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have some questions regarding how Firestore offline persistence works.

- when I save a document does it really get stored locally on my device? Is there some way to view this data (not modify just preview)
- I have an async method that saves a document to firestore.

  - If i use the `await` keyword before the call to `firestore.doc().set()`, the application freezes (i.e. i have a loader and it just spins indefinitely) which shouldn't be the default behaviour assuming persistence is enabled.
  - And if i remove the `await` keyword, flutter executes other codes below `firestore.doc().set()`
    So my question is, when using `await` shouldn't firestore persist the data to local (the default) and when the device is connected to the internet upload the pending writes to firestore? however, this is not the case

Here's a simple function to write and read some data from firestore:

```dart
Future<Map<String, dynamic>?> getSomeData() async {
  final dto = UserDTO(id: "random-id", name: "John Doe", age: 12, createdAt: null);

  final doc = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('organizations')
      .doc('some-org-id')
      .collection("facilities")
      .doc('some-facility-id')
      .collection('users')
      .doc(dto.id);

  // should automatically write to cache if no internet otherwise write to Firestore db
  await doc.set(dto.toJson(), SetOptions(merge: true));

  // ====== if i use await above, everything below this line is not executed because the future is not completed yet. Which should not be the case? =======

  // should automatically read from cache if no internet otherwise read from Firestore db
  final snapshot = await doc.get();

  return snapshot.data();
}
```

if i `await` the set call, everything below that line does not get executed until the device has internet.
And firestore would continously retry the `set` method which would keep throwing the error:

```bash
W/Firestore(12100): (24.6.0) [WatchStream]: (619e0c7) Stream closed with status: Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=Unable to resolve host firestore.googleapis.com, cause=java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "firestore.googleapis.com": No address associated with hostname
W/Firestore(12100):     at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver.resolveAddresses(DnsNameResolver.java:223)
W/Firestore(12100):     at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver.doResolve(DnsNameResolver.java:282)
W/Firestore(12100):     at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver$Resolve.run(DnsNameResolver.java:318)
```

**What i tried:**

- Removing `await` and allowing the `.set()` future to complete whenever the device comes online. This works, however, its difficult to handle Firestore exceptions with this approach.
- Using `.then()` and `.catchError()` instead of `await`; which I dont really like to use because it makes everything more complex and throws code readability out the IDE.
- Using flutter's `Completer` class. Same as `.then()`
- Reading the [Flutter Firebase Firestore documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline) and I could not find any mention of this in the docs